# Wrong URL for images when not using a domainname

Tags: joomla-2.5

We're running our sites on a VPS - 
When we're running our sites *with* a domain name, all images are detected just fine,
but when we're running it from our pre-production thing on the VPS, 
the URL generated into the CSS should be: `vps.com/~sitethingy/images/etc`
but it is generated as `vps.com/images/etc` instead.

We're using the JURI::root function.

Any idea how to fix this so it'll work on our pre-production sites as well?

Comment: What happens if you use `JUri::base()` ?

Comment: Another way to solve this is to add `RewriteBase /~sitethingy` to the `.htaccess` file although maybe not a long term solution.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Will put this as a proper answer for a reference.

Rather than using `JUri::root()`, you need to use `JUri::base()`.

The difference being (I think) is that `root` can be overridden, where as `base` can't be. Might be wrong, but hopefully someone can clarify this.